# Как показывать несколько уведомлений с прогрессами?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-service, android-notification

Написал сервис для скачивания файлов, показываю прогресс загрузки в уведомлении, в конце загрузки перестраиваю уведомление. Надо, чтобы при каждом запуске создавалось новое уведомление. Как этого добиться? Ума не приложу куда что писать, по сути сервис пересоздается.

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService
{
public static final int NOTIFY_ID = 108;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
boolean isProgress;
public DownloadService()
{
    super("DownloadService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + fileName);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        showNotification(fileName, 0);
        int progress = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            total += count;
            int newProgress = (int) total * 100 / fileLength;
            if(newProgress >= progress + 20){
            progress = newProgress;
            showNotification(fileName, progress);
            }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    finally{

    }
}

public void showNotification(String fileName, int progress)
{
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker("Загрузка");
    builder.setContentTitle(fileName);
    if(progress >= 100){
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.done);
        builder.setContentText("Загрузка завершена");
    }
    else{
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
    builder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
    }
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);        
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уведомления имеют `ID` по которому система и решает что вы пытаетесь делать - изменять уже отображаемое уведомление или хотите показать ещё одно. Этот `ID` вы передаёте первым аргументом метода `notify`, т.е. вам надо передавать туда в коде не константу как сейчас, но нужное число.

Comment: Да, я это сделал :) Константу заменил переменной, в `onHandleIntent` ее инициализирую рандомным числом. Но вот уведомления встают в очередь, тоесть когда сервис прекратит скачивать, запускается следующий. Как можно сразу создавать второй сервис? Почему он ждет завершения запущенного?

Comment: @Flippy, потому что он так устроен. Вам надо или кардинально переписывать сам класс `Service` или использовать другие инструменты. Как мне кажется сервис в таком случае будет вообще не обязателен. Попробуйте синглтон из которого через RxJava стартовать сетевые запросы.

Comment: В моей IDE нет поддержки RxJava... :( А как же тогда устроен механизм загрузок в Chrome? В нем файлы качаются не по очереди а вместе. Стоит ли смотреть в сторону работы с уведомлениями прямо в активности?

Comment: @Flippy, ну, попробуйте тогда просто через Thread делать. А с активити так делать не стоит - пересоздастся она и не сможет получать сообщения о, например окончании загрузки.

Comment: Сейчас попробую :)

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!